# LINQ to Entities Initialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I currently have the :below: code for generating a list of all current 'rides' in an sql db table.. However, it seems that although there is data in the table, I am not able to access it. Am I missing an initialization step? Other thoughts?

```
using (RamRideOpsEntities myEntities = new RamRideOpsEntities())
        {
            var adminOptions = (from a in myEntities.AdminOptions
                                select new { a.ValidDate1, a.ValidDate2 }).First();

            var allRides = (from r in myEntities.Rides
                         where (r.TimeOfCall == adminOptions.ValidDate1 ||
                                r.TimeOfCall == adminOptions.ValidDate2)
                         orderby r.TimeOfCall descending
                         select r).ToList();

            TextBox1.Text = allRides[0].Name; // <- Seems there are no existing objects as rides[0] is out of bounds
        }
```

Comment: Please specify what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `allRides.First().Name`?

Comment: Yes, I tried allRides.FirstOrDefault() and it returns null.
@Kate : The problem is that although there are objects in the table, my list does not seem to be grabbing any of them.

Comment: Try to hover mouse on the allRides during debugging and you will se the generated sql code. Select it, copy it and run in on your db and see if it returns something. And you will able to check if the generated sql is doing what you need.

Comment: @kate Turns out it was a date problem, it was checking a date value that also contained a time so the chance of it ever exactly equaling the stored date/time exactly was almost nil. So I made a couple changes and all is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the adminOptions variable to confirm whether or not it contains what you intend for it to contain?

The ValidDate1 and ValidDate2 properties of the adminOptions variable are the only conditions of the allRides query that are external to the Rides table, so my guess is that the allRides query might be OK; however, there may be an issue with the adminOptions query.